Zsh - Nixos Autocompletion/Auto Suggestions duplicate strange behavior
I'm trying out nixos, and I've wrote a zsh.nix to bootstrap the zsh environment:
{config, pkgs, lib, inputs, ...}:

let
  cfg = {
    enable = true;
    enableCompletion = true;
    autosuggestion.enable = true;
    history.expireDuplicatesFirst = true;
    syntaxHighlighting.enable = true;
    oh-my-zsh = {
      enable = true;
      theme = "robbyrussell";
      plugins = [
        "fzf"
        "golang"
        "helm"
        "dotnet"
        "docker"
        "docker-compose"
        "emoji"
        "eza"
        "direnv"
        "git"
        "zsh-interactive-cd"
        "kubectl"
      ];
      extraConfig = ''
        zstyle ':completion:*:*:docker:*' option-stacking yes
        zstyle ':completion:*:*:docker-*:*' option-stacking yes
        zstyle ':omz:plugins:docker' legacy-completion yes
      '';
    };
    initExtra = ''
            export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
            export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
    ''
  };
in {
  config = cfg;
}

Its's behaving strangely, as far as I noticed when I paste anything into the terminal:
As you can see in the image/gif attached bellow:

Sometimes I'm not able to delete the first char
Sometimes when I try to use the auto suggestions, I get a strange behavior while trying to edit the command. I don't know with this gif you can notice that, I can try to make a better one if needed.



Do you have any ideas why this is happening?

Never mind, I've just figure out...
The main problem was happening because i had a function to get my distro and apply the icons.
Somehow it was breaking the line and presenting this strange behavior.
#! /bin/zsh
function run() {
    LFILE="/etc/*-release"
    MFILE="/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist"
    if [[ -f $LFILE ]]; then
    _distro=$(awk '/^ID=/' /etc/*-release | awk -F'=' '{ print tolower($2) }')
    elif [[ -f $MFILE ]]; then
    _distro="macos"

    # on mac os use the systemprofiler to determine the current model
    _device=$(system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | awk '/Model Name/ {print $3,$4,$5,$6,$7}')

    case $_device in
        *MacBook*)     DEVICE="";;
        *mini*)        DEVICE="";;
        *)             DEVICE="";;
    esac
    fi

    # set an icon based on the distro
    # make sure your font is compatible with https://github.com/lukas-w/font-logos
    case $_distro in
        *kali*)                  ICON="ﴣ";;
        *arch*)                  ICON="";;
        *debian*)                ICON="";;
        *raspbian*)              ICON="";;
        *ubuntu*)                ICON="";;
        *elementary*)            ICON="";;
        *fedora*)                ICON="";;
        *coreos*)                ICON="";;
        *gentoo*)                ICON="";;
        *mageia*)                ICON="";;
        *centos*)                ICON="";;
        *opensuse*|*tumbleweed*) ICON="";;
        *sabayon*)               ICON="";;
        *slackware*)             ICON="";;
        *linuxmint*)             ICON="";;
        *alpine*)                ICON="";;
        *aosc*)                  ICON="";;
        *nixos*)                 ICON="";;
        *devuan*)                ICON="";;
        *manjaro*)               ICON="";;
        *rhel*)                  ICON="";;
        *macos*)                 ICON="";;
        *)                       ICON="";;
esac

export STARSHIP_DISTRO=$ICON;
export STARSHIP_DEVICE="$DEVICE"
export STARSHIP_CONFIG="$DOT_FILES_DIR/starship/starship.toml"
}
run

which was imported into my .zshrc
    [[ -f $DOT_FILES_DIR/zsh/starship.zsh ]] && source $DOT_FILES_DIR/zsh/starship.zsh && [[ $print_scripts_loaded == "true" ]] && echo "Starship loaded"

Now I'm just exporting the STARSHIP_CONFIG and using their os and os.symbol modules
    #! /bin/zsh
    function run() {
    export STARSHIP_CONFIG="$DOT_FILES_DIR/starship/starship.toml"
    }
    run

If anyone wondering how the config looks like
"$schema" = 'https://starship.rs/config-schema.json'
add_newline = false
command_timeout = 1000
format = """
$os\
$username\
$hostname\
$kubernetes\
$directory\
$git_branch\
$git_status\
$cmd_duration\
$character\
$fill\
$memory_usage\
$time\
\n\
[➜ ](bold blue)
"""
[fill]
symbol=' '
[memory_usage]
disabled =false
threshold=1
format="[$ram](bold blue) $symbol"
symbol=" "

[time]
disabled = false
style="bold blue"
format=" [$time](green)   "

[character] # The name of the module we are configuring is 'character'
success_symbol = '[](bold green)' # The 'success_symbol' segment is being set to '➜' with the color 'bold green'
error_symbol = '[✗](bold red)' # The 'success_symbol' segment is being set to '➜' with the color 'bold green'


[os]
format = '[$symbol](bold white) '   
disabled = false

[os.symbols]
Alpaquita = " "
Alpine = " "
AlmaLinux = " "
Amazon = " "
Android = " "
Arch = " "
Artix = " "
CentOS = " "
Debian = " "
DragonFly = " "
Emscripten = " "
EndeavourOS = " "
Fedora = " "
FreeBSD = " "
Garuda = " "
Gentoo = " "
HardenedBSD = " "
Illumos = " "
Kali = " "
Linux = " "
Mabox = " "
Macos = " "
Manjaro = " "
Mariner = " "
MidnightBSD = " "
Mint = " "
NetBSD = " "
NixOS = " "
OpenBSD = " "
openSUSE = " "
OracleLinux = " "
Pop = " "
Raspbian = " "
Redhat = " "
RedHatEnterprise = " "
RockyLinux = " "
Redox = " "
Solus = " "
SUSE = " "
Ubuntu = " "
Unknown = " "
Void = " "
Windows = " "

[username]
style_user = 'white bold'
style_root = 'black bold'
format = '[$user]($style) '
disabled = false
show_always = true

[hostname]
ssh_only = false
format = 'on [$hostname](bold yellow) '
disabled = false


[directory]
truncation_length = 1
truncation_symbol = '…/'
home_symbol = ' ~'
read_only_style = '197'
read_only = '  '
format = 'at [$path]($style)[$read_only]($read_only_style) '


# Shows current git branch
[git_branch]
symbol = ' '
format = 'via [$symbol$branch]($style)'
# truncation_length = 4
truncation_symbol = '…/'
style = 'bold green'

# Shows current git status
[git_status]
format = '[$all_status$ahead_behind]($style) '
style = 'bold green'
conflicted = ''
up_to_date = ''
untracked = ' '
ahead = '⇡${count}'
diverged = '⇕⇡${ahead_count}⇣${behind_count}'
behind = '⇣${count}'
stashed = '  '
modified = ' '
staged = '[++\($count\)](green)'
renamed = '襁 '
deleted = ' '

# Shows kubernetes context and namespace
[kubernetes]
format = 'via [ $context\($namespace\)](bold purple) '
disabled = false

# ---

[vagrant]
disabled = true

[docker_context]
disabled = true

[helm]
disabled = true

[python]
disabled = true

[nodejs]
disabled = true

[ruby]
disabled = true

[terraform]
disabled = true

[cmd_duration]
format='[$duration](bold cyan) '
min_time=5

